# Comparing averages of unequal population sizes

Tags: sampling, sample-size, mean, population

Imagine the following problem: I have 1000 plots of land. On each plot of land I plant 1000 Oak trees and 1 Elm tree. Each plot of land differs in multiple parameters (e.g. sunlight, soil type, rainfall, etc).

After 10 years I want to compare the height of the Oak trees to the Elm trees. I first want to see if, on average, the Elm trees have grown more than the Oak trees. I can take the height of each Elm tree from the 1000 plots of land and get the mean height of Elm trees across all plots of land. However, it would take far too long to measure the height of all 1000 Oak trees on each plot of land, so I need to take a sample from each plot. How do I determine the minimum sample size of Oak trees to take from each plot, to make a comparison of average tree height between Oak and Elm trees? Can I just measure 1 from each plot, as only 1 Elm tree was measured in each?

Comment: Looks like you need power analysis.